Sharepoint Online Calendar to Database - PowerShell
I need help writing a Powershell script that will insert an existing SharePoint Online calendar into the database.
So far I've managed to find a few examples on the forums, but I'm unable to create a script that will allow me to get all the data from the calendar, including recurring events.
Here's what I've tried so far:
 #Setup Credentials to connect
$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName,(ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force))
 
#Set up the context
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)
$Context.Credentials = $credentials
  
#Get the List
$List = $Context.web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListName)
 
#Get all List items from the library Including Items in Sub-Folder
$Query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
$Query.ViewXml=
 "<View>
  <Query>
    <Where>
      <DateRangesOverlap>
        <FieldRef Name='EventDate' />
        <FieldRef Name='EndDate' />
        <FieldRef Name='RecurrenceID' />
        <Value Type='DateTime'>
          <Now />
        </Value>
      </DateRangesOverlap>
    </Where>
    <OrderBy>
      <FieldRef Name='EventDate'></FieldRef>
    </OrderBy>     
  </Query>
   <queryOptions>
        <QueryOptions>
          <RecurrencePatternXMLVersion>v3</RecurrencePatternXMLVersion>
          <ExpandRecurrence>TRUE</ExpandRecurrence>
          <RecurrenceOrderBy>TRUE</RecurrenceOrderBy>
        </QueryOptions>
      </queryOptions>
  <ViewAttributes Scope='RecursiveAll' />
</View>"
$ListItems = $List.GetItems($Query)
$context.Load($ListItems)
$context.ExecuteQuery()
 
#Array to Hold List Items
$ListItemCollection = @()
 
  $iNumber=1 
            foreach ($splListItem in $ListItems) 
            { 
                        $ExportItem = New-Object PSObject
                        $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Title" -value $splListItem.FieldValues.Title
                        $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "StartTime" -value $splListItem.FieldValues.EventDate
                        $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "EndTime" -value $splListItem.FieldValues.EndDate
                        #$ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Created" -value $splListItem.FieldValues.Created
                        $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ModifyTime" -value $splListItem.FieldValues.Modified
                        if ($splListItem.FieldValues.Podaci_x0020_od_x0020_dana){
                        $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Podaci" -value $splListItem.FieldValues.Podaci_x0020_od_x0020_dana}
                        else {$ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Podaci" -value $splListItem.FieldValues.EventDate;} 

                        #Add the object with property to an Array
                        $ListItemCollection += $ExportItem
            }

this code allows me to get events but not the recurring ones.
